# Grails initialization

Tags: spring, grails

In my Grails app, I need access to configuration exposed by a Java class similar to the below

```
public class Config {

  private Properties properties = new Properties(); 

  static load(String path) {
    File configFile = new File(path);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(configFile);
    properties.load(fileReader);
  }

  String getProperty(String name) {
    properties.getProperty(name);
  }
}
```

I trigger the initialisation of this class in the first line of `Bootstrap.groovy` by calling `Config.load("/conf.properties")`. However, the initialization of various Spring beans needs properties that are exposed by `Config`, but by the time `Bootstrap.groovy` is executed, Spring initialization has already completed.

So I need to find a way to call `Config.load()` before construction of the Spring beans, is this possible? I guess there might be an event handler available in `/script/_Events.groovy` that I could invoke it from, but I'm not sure which handlers are available.

Unfortunately, changing the source code of `Config.java` isn't an option, and neither is eliminating my usage of this class.

Comment: What about creating a Spring bean which calls this bean during initialization?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore could you provide a code sample that illustrates how I would create a Spring bean that does this? I need this Spring bean to be invoked before any other Spring beans are constructed and am not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try declaring a suitable bean in `web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`, which is the definition of the root web application context as opposed to the GrailsApplication's internal context.

```
<bean id="initConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetClass" value="com.example.Config" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="load" />
  <property name="arguments">
    <list><value>/conf.properties</value></list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and modify the `grailsApplication` bean to depend on that:

```
<bean id="grailsApplication" depends-on="initConfig" class="...">
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Is it OK to modify `web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` or is it only supposed to be used internally by the framework?

Comment: @Dónal I don't see why you can't change it, though any changes will be overwritten when you upgrade between Grails versions and would have to be re-instated by hand.